# PostgreSQL reusing computed result as input to other select computations

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way we can take a computed result inside the select clause and insert it into another computation inside the select clause?

For example this is what I want to have but can't so far:

```
select trim(leading https://www.amazon.com for url) as trimmedURL,

substring(trimmedURL, from position('/' in trimmedURL) for position ('html' in trimmedURL))....
```

As you can see I have used trimmedURL 3 times inside the substring function. I know how to naively do that be copy/paste of trim(leading https://www.amazon.com for url) into the substring function. 
Is there any way to avoid that and not create really large function calls as the first value computed might be placed many times inside other functions. This will improve code readability and usability.

Comment: can you provide a more complete example, exactly what kind of duplication are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `lateral join` and place the computed fields i the lateral query. the lateral fields are then accessible from the main query.

[Postgres documentation for lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)

i.e.

```
SELECT
  trimmedUrl
, SUBSTRING(trimmedURL,10,20) url_part 
FROM mytable
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT trim(leading https://www.amazon.com for url) as trimmedURL) trmd 
               ON TRUE
```

also, note that postgresql ignores casing in the naming of columns / tables etc unless they are quoted.

Here's a self-contained example:

```
WITH x(col) AS (Values ('abc://cdf/def'), ('abc://xyz/pqr'))
SELECT x.col, SUBSTRING(y.col2 from position('/' in y.col2)) resuing_computation
FROM x
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT trim(leading 'abc://' from col) col2) y ON TRUE
```